# how do I subtract one week from this date in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my code

```
var myDate = new Date();
todaysDate = ((myDate.getDate()) + '/' + (myDate.getMonth()) + '/' + (myDate.getFullYear()));
$('#txtEndDate').val(todaysDate);
```

I need txtEndDate's value = today's date - one week

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

You can modify a date using `setDate`. It automatically corrects for shifting to new months/years etc.

```
var oneWeekAgo = new Date();
oneWeekAgo.setDate(oneWeekAgo.getDate() - 7);
```

And then go ahead to render the date to a string in any matter you prefer.

Comment: its setting the date as this ..Tue Dec 06 2011 18:24:34 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)  ..I need the date to be in this format ...13/11/2011  how do I do that now? plz help..thanks

Comment: You may format it exactly as you like. The above code is for getting the date that is exactly one week from now. You can then go ahead and format it exactly as you're currently doing with `todaysDate` using `...getDate() + '/' ...`. Do note that `getMonth()` is 0-based, which is why you're getting `11` for December, there...

Comment: @Asad I can confirm David's right here - it does work across month boundaries

Answer (score 24):

I'd do something like

```
var myDate = new Date();
var newDate = new Date(myDate.getTime() - (60*60*24*7*1000));
```

Comment: so would I, but be aware of funny effects if the two dates are either side of daylight savings time.

Comment: Huge help! I like this method a bit more. I'm obsessed with one-liners though. So I use this: 


`var date = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (60*60*24*7*1000));`

Comment: You don't need the `.getTime()`. This works just as well: `new Date(new Date() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 1000)`.

Comment: @DanDascalescu wouldnt that invoke a whole new date generation? not that it would make much difference depending on the use case but id imagine less class construction the better

Answer (score 9):

```
var now = new Date();
now.setDate(now.getDate() - 7); // add -7 days to your date variable 
alert(now);
```

Comment: @DanDascalescu, Well, there was a difference of ~2 minutes between posts (5 years back)!

Answer (score 1):

Check out Date.js. Its really neat!

http://www.datejs.com/

Here are a couple of ways to do it using Date.js:

```
// today - 7 days
// toString() is just to print it to the console all pretty

Date.parse("t - 7 d").toString("MM-dd-yyyy");     // outputs "12-06-2011"
Date.today().addDays(-7).toString("MM-dd-yyyy");  // outputs "12-06-2011"
Date.today().addWeeks(-1).toString("MM-dd-yyyy"); // outputs "12-06-2011"
```

As an unrelated side note, do check out Moment.js as well... I think the 2 libraries compliment each other :)

http://momentjs.com/

Comment: You don't need a library for something as simple as this, let alone a complex one like momentjs.

Comment: @DanDascalescu , correct, but that doesn't warrant a downvote.