# Changing date values stored in array into two weeks ago

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

I have a date array as below:

```
const d = ["2020-06-29T00:00:00.000Z","2020-07-06T00:00:00.000Z","2020-07-13T00:00:00.000Z","2020-07-20T00:00:00.000Z","2020-07-27T00:00:00.000Z"];
```

I want to shift every element in the date array into two weeks earlier from the date using forEach below from the method I found here [how do I subtract one week from this date in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489500/how-do-i-subtract-one-week-from-this-date-in-jquery)

```
d.forEach(d.setDate(d.getdate() - 14));
```

However, I receive error while what I want is all date has shifted into two weeks earlier as below:

```
const d = ["2020-06-15T00:00:00.000Z","2020-06-22T00:00:00.000Z","2020-06-29T00:00:00.000Z","2020-07-13T00:00:00.000Z","2020-07-20T00:00:00.000Z"];
```

Comment: You have an array of `string`s, not `date`s. Convert them and do the operations

Comment: And `forEach` takes a function as a callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **forEach** loop  you can achieve this

```js
const d = ["2020-06-29T00:00:00.000Z","2020-07-06T00:00:00.000Z","2020-07-13T00:00:00.000Z","2020-07-20T00:00:00.000Z","2020-07-27T00:00:00.000Z"];


var res = [];
d.forEach(obj => {
   var tempDate = new Date(obj);
   tempDate.setDate(tempDate.getDate() -14);
   res.push(tempDate.toISOString());
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Why are 3 `new Date()` objects being created in every iteration when you only need 1?

Comment: Updated the answer. Thank you letting me know @adiga

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as below (Converting `string` to `date` and using `.map()`):

```js
const d = ["2020-06-29T00:00:00.000Z","2020-07-06T00:00:00.000Z","2020-07-13T00:00:00.000Z","2020-07-20T00:00:00.000Z","2020-07-27T00:00:00.000Z"]
, result = d.map(curr => {
  const dt = new Date(curr)
  dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 14)
  return dt.toISOString()
})

console.log(result);
```